# Solving the equation in Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2(x + y -1)$ then find value of $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 $

1. $2$
2. $0$
3. $-1$
4. $1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite like this

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2x-2y+2 =0$$

then

$$x^2-2x +1 +y^2-2y+1+z^2 =0$$

so

$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+z^2 =0$$

thus $x=y=1$ and $z=0$ so $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 2$.

Comment: Thanks man ... I didn't have clue how should i approach